# minecraft wont download on my Macbook

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I had minecraft on my computer before but was playing through a file in evernote (if that makes sense. I saved the application from my iPod into evernote then opened it on my computer. I'm not sure how, but it worked :P) now I'm trying to download the application from minecraft.net but it won't download correctly. The file is supposed to be 270 kb but in downloads it says its only 149 kb. When I try to open the application, a pop up comes up and says "minecraft is damaged and can't be opened. You should move it to the trash" 
Everything is current on my computer. Any ideas on what to do?

Comment: Sounds like a corrupted download.  Re-download the application.

Comment: I have several times

Comment: How do you know it's supposed to be 270kb?  Are you sure you're downloading the correct file?

Comment: On minecrafts site i go to download and it says "Minecraft for Mac OS X" then under it is a link that says "minecraft.zip (270 KB) and yes I'm sure I'm clicking on the mac version

Comment: Any reason you can't just copy it out of Evernote and use that? It's just the launcher anyway—you have the actual game files already.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, dragging it from evernote into applications. But the controls my mom put on mg computer require a password every time I play it XP but hey it works and I was able to retrieve my world's so I'm happy. :P

Comment: @Warface: just an FYI, that's a dead link and violation of Minecraft's [Terms and Conditions](http://minecraft.net/terms).

Answer (score 2):

That is Gatekeeper (built into Mountain Lion). Since Minecraft isn't on the App Store, OS X won't let you run it. See [this article](http://osxdaily.com/2012/07/27/app-cant-be-opened-because-it-is-from-an-unidentified-developer/) for details on how to get around it. You can also go to the `Security` panel in System Preferences and disable Gatekeeper.
I had the same problem, and this worked.

Comment: @Caitlin doesn't mention that it's Mountain Lion, and the error that the OP gives is different than the error that's given when [Gatekeeper keeps you from opening an application](http://cache.gizmodo.com/assets/images/4/2012/02/0c891df75f847d032be74960b23dc10a.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to download the Linux version and then run it just run it (use command-line arguments if you want). Minecraft.jar can be put anywhere.

Your current issue is probably a downloading problem. Try turning off your firewall.